# Cubic polynomial given linear reminders after division by quadratic polynomials

Tags: polynomials, roots, factoring

$$f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+3x+4$$
$f(x)$ leaves a remainder of $-3x+3$ when divided by $x^2-1$.
What would you suggest to solve for a and b solely using the remainder, factor and the integral zero theorems?

Comment: Adapt any of the answers under the closely related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3770874/given-that-fx-is-a-polynomial-of-degree-3-and-its-remainders-are-2x-5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(1) = -3\cdot 1+3 = 0\implies a+b+7 = 0$. Also $f(-1) = -3\cdot (-1)+3 = 6 \implies -a+b+1=6 $. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Great! Thank you

Comment: You are welcome.